# Allegro4 and Allegro5 dev seems to not want to install together

Tags: package-management, libraries

Installing via `synapic` on a new Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the allegro 4 and 5 development packages Ubuntu seem to act as if mutually exclusive and give me an exclamation point saying that one will need to be uninstalled for the other. Is this the case for other people, and if so can this be fixed? Should I install via source like I normally do? I was just really happy to see allegro 4 AND 5 in the Ubuntu Repos.

This is normal behavior for most libraries which have upgrades, but is not necessary (and detrimental ) for Allegro, for which Allegro 4 and Allegro 5 are nearly as similar as OpenGL is to OpenSSL from the computers point of view. This is because there was an entire rewrite between 4 and 5 and there is no expected compatibility. That said installed allegro4-dev should probably point out that alleg5-dev would be better as the allegro project community has all but moved on, save for projects that will not be re-written.

Packages Possibly Affected:

1. liballegro4-dev
2. liballegro5-dev

If other people have this issue too, a bug-report will have to be filed. Otherwise, I am just looking for the solution to allowing both without breaking my package manager.